# How to transform an existing column in foreign key using Laravel Migrations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having trouble trying to change a column type in laravel to fits it as a compatible column to be a foreign key referencing another table id fields.

I have a a schema like this:

```
Schema::create('person_organization', function(Blueprint $table){
   ...

   $table->integer('organization_id');
   ...
});
```

and I want to change the field `organization_id` to an unsigned type, which will make it able to be a foreign key referencing the `id` field in the `organizations` table.

**NOTE:** Just changing the field type in the creation of the table is not an available option, because the system is running in production mode.

So we need to make a new migration to do these changes.

**NOTE 2:**  i tried the method `change` as described in [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#changing-columns), but it sticks in a query error, as following:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') on delete cascade' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `person_organization` add constraint `person_organization_person_id_foreign` foreign key (`person_id`) references `persons` () on delete cascade)

Comment: "i tried the method change as described in laravel docs, but it stucks in a query error."  what error?

Comment: @lagbox post the query error

Comment: @iagbox i have updated the question with the query error.

Comment: can you post the code you tried?

Comment: `Schema::table('person_organization', function (Blueprint $table) {
            
            // Organization
            $table->integer('organization_id')->unsigned()->change();
            $table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations')->onDelete('cascade');
            // Person
            $table->integer('person_id')->unsigned()->change();
            $table->foreign('person_id')->referenes('id')->on('persons')->onDelete('cascade');
        });`

@AlexandreThebaldi

Comment: why are you changing domain_organization table? aren't you modifying persons table?

Comment: Is it a many-to-many relationship table. @salman-zafar. 

but this doesn't matter, because the error is not linked to the table, but with the laravel quqery error during the query.

Comment: try this: Schema::table('persons', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('organization_id')->unsigned()->index()->change();
              $table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

Comment: @SalmanZafar i'll try and post here the result.

Comment: @ThauanCSantos okay sure

Comment: @SalmanZafar Worked for Me. Can you post your answer as an answer below, so i can rate it as the correct answer.

Comment: @ThauanCSantos posted my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering you have already installed **doctrine/dbal** package in your application
Now create migration `php artisan make:migration your_migration_name` and then in migration insert the below code.

```
    Schema::table('persons', function(Blueprint $table) { 
    $table->integer('organization_id')->unsigned()->index()->change(); 
    $table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations')- 
  >onDelete('cascade'); 
})
```

now run command `php artisan migrate` and now your are done.
Happy coding...

Comment: it's not working in laravel 8. Is there a different way to add a foreign key to existing column

Answer (score 2):

From Laravel 5.6 docs:

> Before modifying a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your  composer.json file.

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Then create the migration:

```
php artisan make:migration add_organization_foreign_to_persons_table --table=persons
```

And:

```
Schema::table('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('organization_id')->change();
    $table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations');
});
```

Comment: i just have `docrtine/dbal` in installed. i have updated the question showing the error. @Alexandre Thebaldi

Answer (score -1):

```
$table->integer('organization_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: It was to modify a column/add constraint on a table inside an already existing (migrated) migration. This code only works if you are creating a new table/column.